# combinatorial interpretation for series sum

Tags: combinatorics

$$S_n = 1^1 + 2^2+ 3^3 + \dots + (n-1)^{(n-1)} + n^n$$
what could be the combinatorial interpretation for the above sum $S_n$?
Regards
vishal

Answer (score 1):

It may not be very useful, but here is one possible combinatorial interpretation of $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^nk^k$.

You have a deck of $n$ cards bearing the integers $1$ through $n$, one to a card. You perform the following experiment.

> Pick an integer $k\in\{1,\dots,n\}$. Form a smaller deck containing cards $1$ through $k$. From this short deck draw $k$ cards at random with replacement, and record the sequence of draws.

$S_n$ is the number of possible outcomes of the experiment.